# directfb driver not found when using static embedded qt

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, directfb

I want to build static embedded qt. So I performed these steps:

1- In qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.0/mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++/qmake.conf file, I added directfb as below:

```
QT_CFLAGS_DIRECTFB      = -I${DIRECTFB_DIR}/include/directfb -D_REENTRANT
QT_LIBS_DIRECTFB        = -L${DIRECTFB_DIR}/lib -ldirect -ldirectfb -lfusion
```

2- Directfb shared libraries are present in target rootfs in /lib/directfb

3- Configure and build qt:

```
./configure -v -embedded -platform qws/linux-x86_64-g++ -xplatform qws/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -plugin-gfx-directfb -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -static -opensource -nomake examples -confirm-license -nomake demos -nomake docs -nomake translations -prefix output -no-fast -no-qt3support -no-libmng -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-declarative-debug -no-ssse3 -no-sse4.1 -no-nis -no-cups -no-gtkstyle -no-glib -no-nas-sound -no-opengl -no-openvg -no-sse4.2 -no-avx -no-neon
make
make install
```

The result is generated in output directory.

4- I copied output/lib/fonts in target /lib directory

5- Build my qt application

6- Run the application in the target:

```
export QT_QWS_FONTDIR=/lib/
./my_qt_application -qws -display directfb
```

Then I got this error:

```
directfb: driver not found
```

Could you please help me on this ?

Comment: maybe this can help : http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/14514-Problem-with-Qt-embedded-4-4-0-static-amp-directfb

Comment: @Mali I added in my main application these includes #include <QtPlugin>

Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(directfb) but I got this error when building the application: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2c): undefined reference to `qt_plugin_instance_directfb()'